# Add a breakline in ActiveAdmin without using para

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How to add a break line in ActiveAdmin without using `para`?

Having something like that:

```
panel 'Order' do
  order.id
  br order.price
end
```

Instead of

```
panel 'Order' do
  para order.id
  para order.price
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Surround every ouput with arbre html elements like so:

```
panel 'Order' do
  span { order.id }
  br
  span { order.price }
end
```

You can also set html attributes this way:

```
panel 'Order' do
  span(:id => 'myownspanid') { order.id }
  br(:style => 'line-height: 27px')
  span { order.price }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave could be rewritten:

```
panel 'Order' do
  attributes_table_for order do
    row :id
    row :price
  end
end
```

order would normally be an ActiveRecord model, but it could also be a Draper decorator or even an OpenStruct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `html` method if you don't want the text placed in a particular element.

```
panel 'Order' do
  html order.id
  br 
  html order.price
end
```